# Selenium - Calendar Picker - Select Current Day NoSuchElementException Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, nosuchelementexception

The issue was with my method of navigating the page.  I have to select the actual calendar then select the current date.  Code below is the updated and correct code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#navigates to website 
driver.get('https://www.sosnc.gov/online_services/search/by_title/_Business_Registration_changes')

#select calendar
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/article/div/form/article/section/div/div[2]/label').click()
time.sleep(3)

#select current calendar date
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui-datepicker-today').click()
time.sleep(2)

#select and click search button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search"]').click()
```

Comment: `this pulls info from the previous and current day` which element exactly?

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have updated the code above to the correct code with explanation to the solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#navigates to website 
driver.get('https://www.sosnc.gov/online_services/search/by_title/_Business_Registration_changes')

#select calendar
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/article/div/form/article/section/div/div[2]/label').click()
time.sleep(3)

#select current calendar date
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui-datepicker-today').click()
time.sleep(2)

#select and click search button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search"]').click()
```